# How to jump to the beginning of the next column when adding new data into text file?

Tags: python, text, printing, format

I have written a python script which starts with an empty `.txt` file. It adds a series of numeric data into first column of the file and then it closes the file. The code is actually running 3 times and it is supposed to print data into a new column presumably after inserting an empty column so that by the end of the code, we should end up with a `.txt` file which has 3 columns of data corresponding to 3 runs. I have managed to set the code to run three times and produce 3 1d arrays with known elements (known as "some_array").

Here is the snippet of the code that writes data into a `.txt` file.

```
# "some_array" which is updated for each run
data = "<Path to data.txt>"
with open(data,"a") as fName:
    for item in some_array:
        print('{:.2e}'.format(item), file=fName)
    fName.close()
```

Which would result in the following output: 
(Unfortunately, all data are added at the end of the previous set of data)

```
1.00e-3
2.00e-3
3.00e-3
4.00e-3
5.00e-3
6.00e-3
7.00e-3
8.00e-3
9.00e-3
```

Is there any way to insert an empty column and jump to the beginning of the next column **right before** closing the file? This way I can get three columns of data, something like this:

```
1.00e-3 4.00e-3 7.00e-3
2.00e-3 5.00e-3 8.00e-3
3.00e-3 6.00e-3 9.00e-3
```

Comment: you can write line by line in a file, not by column by column. so, you can write lines as "1 4 7", "2 5 8" and "3 6 9".

Comment: What if "1 2 3" are printed in a column and I cannot change that but just want to move the next data set to the next column? Each column has its own physical meaning and I am not supposed to mix them.

Comment: You have to rewrite the entire file to add anything to each line.

Comment: If you can keep the columns in memory, you can write them in the very end using `zip` and `print((ncols*' {:.2e}').format(*item), file=fName)`

Comment: So do you mean that I should create 3 memory files before zipping them together? The problem is that this job is done twice in the code. So, I guess I have to end up creating six files. Right?

Comment: No, I mean you'd create three distinct `some_array`s and then loop `for item in zip(some_array1, some_array2, some_array3):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Each time you read the file content first and then writing back the content to file, you can prepend previous information.

```
data = "file.txt"
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
with open(data, "r") as fName:
    content = fName.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

with open(data, "w") as fName:
    for i in range(len(array1)):
        if len(content) > i:
            print(content[i] + '\t' + '{:.2e}'.format(array1[i]), file=fName)
        else:
            print('{:.2e}'.format(array1[i]), file=fName)


array2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
with open(data, "r") as fName:
    content = fName.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]

with open(data, "w") as fName:
    for i in range(len(array2)):
        if len(content) > i:
            print(content[i] + '\t' + '{:.2e}'.format(array2[i]), file=fName)
        else:
            print('{:.2e}'.format(array2[i]), file=fName)

array3 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
with open(data, "r") as fName:
    content = fName.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]

with open(data, "w") as fName:
    for i in range(len(array3)):
        if len(content) > i:
            print(content[i] + '\t' + '{:.2e}'.format(array3[i]), file=fName)
        else:
            print('{:.2e}'.format(array3[i]), file=fName)
```

**Please note**, this is just an example, you can modify it to achieve your target task

Comment: Yes. This snippet is compatible with the original code that is producing some_array 3 times. Besides all the modifications I needed to make to this answer to match with my original code, I also replaced '\t' with ' ' in order to make it easier to read data and then further analyze them. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you can keep all your data in memory then the easiest is to zip them for writing:

```
# run_computation(j) returns the j-th data array
some_arrays = [run_computation(j) for j in range(n_columns)]
data = "<Path to data.txt>"
with open(data,"wt") as fName:
    for item in zip(*some_arrays):
        print(' '.join(n_columns * ['{:.2e}']).format(*item), file=fName)
```

Comment: This is concise. But I am receiving error message:                                    *for item in zip(*some_array):
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration*
Can you fix it?

Comment: @Allan it is `some_arrays`, not `some_array`. It has to be a list containing all the arrays you want to write. The error suggests to me that you are passing a single array not wrapped in a list.

Comment: You're right but I modified it to the actual name I had in the original code. So, it doesn't really matter. But since it was more than 5 minutes, I could no longer update the edit to reflect the typo. But I am still curious to see if we can actually work this out given its short syntax.

Comment: Are you sure your `some_array` has the required structure? It must be nested, like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`. The whole thing can only work if you supply _all_ the data to write together.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You are right. But the original code already produces the three sets of data one by one printed all in a column. In other words, I do have "some_array" (not some_arrays) already available within the code. So I don't know why did you mean by the first line of your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, they're produced one after the other rather than all at once. I think that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, I see, what data type is your `some_array` precisely? is it a list or a `numpy` array or something still different?

Comment: It's a 1D numpy array in each of its turns. I see what you meant. I think I was not exactly clear about my concern. I still believe that your code will work but more things need to be done to do that. If it wasn't for the specific flow of lines in my original code, I am sure this would have been a good way.